# Is there such a thing as a (cheap) optocoupler with a non-polarised output?

Tags: opto-isolator, component-selection

Standard optocouplers have a polarised input and a polarised output, thus:

[image: optocoupler]

It is possible to get a coupler with a non-polarised *input*, thus:

[image: nonpolarised opto]

However, what I require is an optocoupler with non-polarised *outputs* - for example, having two optotransistors/optodiodes in reverse-parallel. Does such a thing exist, cheaply (i.e. for a comparable price to standard optos)?

I prefer a DIP-4 package, but anything easy to solder by hand would do. And it should be smaller than DIP-8 because otherwise I might as well just use two standard optos in reverse-parallel.

(Note: triac outputs are not suitable, because they latch when passing DC. I just want two normal phototransistors/diodes in reverse-parallel.)

I have googled to no avail.

Comment: Digikey and Mouser have sortable tabular part data.

Comment: Yes they exist, and no, not for the same low price as the simple polarised single transistor output. Most of that type have two anti-series MOSFETs in the output. Look up H11F1 on Digikey, then look for parts similar to that. What about a standard opto operating into a schottky diode bridge rectifier?

Comment: Solid state relay.

Comment: H11F1 looks interesting. But it has a DIP-6 package while only actually using 4 pins. I'm trying to save space on my board. Currently I'm using two optos (2x DIP-4) for each of three data lines. That's the equivalent of a DIP-12 opto, and it's somewhat large.

Comment: Rectifiers and SSRs would similarly take up additional space.

Comment: What kind of signal do you want to switch? It might be easiest to use the phototransitor output to control an analog switch like 74xx1G66.

Comment: Some SPI-type signals, and a 12V programming signal. I tried an analog switch, and they don't work unless the VCC is greater than the signals to be controlled.